# Creating dynamic dashboards depending on a field or filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I'm trying to generate dynamic graphs and dashboards, for example lets say I'm having a field called operator id, where values for it could be sequentially added on towards the future.  So where as I'm giving the user the iframe url in order to view the dashboard.

So what I'm trying to ask is, is it possible to let the user to select the operator id from a drop down or maybe any other ui components within Kibana, so that Kibana would show the appropriate graph, where I shouldn't be creating graphs or dashboards manually to all the operator ids.

Instead if it has a template kinda graph, whenever the user selects an operator id, the graph should change accordingly. So for this to be possible, is there a way to write a script in order for Kibana to create those graphs dynamically?

I went through [this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4489) ticket, which almost says that this feature has been missing after the Kibana v3. Hence [this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2116) ticket gives a work around to generate the graphs based on the url. I'm not sure how feasible this is?

I'm currently using Kibana 5.0!

Hope I'm clear with the question. Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on the next kibana-API plugin,this plugin give you the ability to create visualisation dynamically, by send visualisation state.
For example:

```
    var visPartial1 = {id: "myNewVis"};
 visPartial1["isFullState"] = false;
 visPartial1["visState"] = {visType: 'pie',
 field: 'city.keyword'};
 iWindow.postMessage({actionType:
 "setVisualization", visDefenetion:
 [visPartial1]}, '*
```

[Kibana-API](https://github.com/Webiks/kibana-API)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The answer is link to kibana plugin that resolve the problem, without the link there is no answer

Comment: I know. You don't need to remove the link, just add enough context or code so that even if the link becomes invalid, this answer would stand alone well on itself.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this in Kibana and haven't found a solution of yet. The only thing I came up with is run Grafana next to Kibana because Grafana has templating build in to do exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare a visualization and change its iframe URL to get the result you want.

1. Create a visualization you want. (No need to save!)

   ```
   <iframe src="http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/visualize/create?embed=true&type=area&indexPattern=sample...)" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
   ```
2. Run query on it using Kibana.

   `query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'operator_id:6') // 6 is the value to change`

   ```
   <iframe src="http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/visualize/create?embed=true&type=area&indexPattern=sample ... query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'operator_id:6' ..." height="600" width="800"></iframe>
   ```
3. Copy the iframe URL clicking on `Share Visualization` button. (Don't `Generate Short URL`)

   And later you can change the value as much as you want. E.g:

   ```
   <iframe src="http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/visualize/create?embed=true&type=area&indexPattern=sample ... query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'operator_id:100' ..." height="600" width="800"></iframe>
   ```

   `query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'operator_id:100') // changed 6 to 100`
4. Reload iframe everytime the user chooses `operator_id` from drop down menu.